# pagination in codeigniter not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('specialoffer_model');
    if($this->input->post('btnUpdate'))
    {
        $this->specialoffer_model->addoffer();
    }
    $data['addoffer']=$this->specialoffer_model->addoffer();
    $data1=array(
                'row'=>$data['addoffer']['row'],
                'result'=>$data['addoffer']['result'],
                );
     $config['base_url'] = site_url('specialoffer/index') . '/';
     $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('home');
     $config['per_page'] =2;
     $this->pagination->initialize($config);
     $data1['results'] =
                    $this->specialoffer_model->get_page (
                                $config['per_page'],
                                $this->uri->segment(3));
     $this->load->view('specialoffer',$data1);
}
```

view

```
 echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Only the page links are generated and on click of it the page is refreshed but all the records from the table are displayed whereas i have specified 2 records from the table to be displayed. In short the pagination does not work. Help

Comment: any suggestion or advice please it is urgent

Comment: please post your model code i am pretty sure you have not used the offset and limit clause in your query

Comment: function get_page($num, $offset) 
 {
  $query = $this->db->get('home', $num, $offset);
  return $query;
  }

Comment: try this... return $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use :

```
$this->db->limit($num,$offset);
$query = $this->db->get('home');
return $query->row_array();
```